# Create a scrollbar (appJar)

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface

So I am creating a scroll-bar in appJar to show 10 numbers at a time (1-10, 11-20, etc.), and I am wondering what the best way is to go about this.

Should I create a function to hide the next 10 numbers until the scrollbar (which is a scale, though this might be the wrong method), and then they appear?

I am genuinely lost right now, as I've only started learning how to use appJar about 2 days ago for a project. Any ideas would be a great help. Yes, this is just the gui part, and the Python (3.6) has not been added yet, but will be.

```
from appJar import gui

def press(btn):

    if btn == "1":
       app.setLabel("answer", "1!")
    elif btn == "2":
       app.setLabel("answer", "2!")
    elif btn == "3":
       app.setLabel("answer", "3!")
    elif btn == "4":
       app.setLabel("answer", "4!")
    elif btn == "5":
       app.setLabel("answer", "5!")
    elif btn == "6":
       app.setLabel("answer", "6!")
    elif btn == "7":
       app.setLabel("answer", "7!")
    elif btn == "8":
       app.setLabel("answer", "8!")
    elif btn == "9":
       app.setLabel("answer", "9!")
    elif btn == "10":
        app.setLabel("answer", "10!")
        app.startScrollPane("scroller")
    elif btn == "11":
       app.setLabel("answer", "11!")
    elif btn == "12":
       app.setLabel("answer", "12!")
       app.stopScrollPane("scroller")


app=gui()
app.setFont(20)
app.addButtons(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"], press)
app.addScale("scroller")
app.setScaleChangeFunction("scroller", press)
app.setButton ("1", "1")
app.setButton ("2", "2")
app.setButton ("3", "3")
app.setButton ("4", "4")
app.setButton ("5", "5")
app.setButton ("6", "6")
app.setButton ("7", "7")
app.setButton ("8", "8")
app.setButton ("9", "9")
app.setButton ("10", "10")
app.setButton ("11", "11")
app.setButton ("12", "12")
app.addLabel ("answer", "Pick a Number!")
app.go()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two alternatives here:

1. Create a scrollPane, and utilise the scrollPane's built in scrollbars
2. Link the Scale widget to a function that updates the labels of the buttons

It really depends on how you want the GUI to look...

For option 1, try the following, instead of the scale:

```
app.startScrollPane("p1")
for i in range(1,101):
    app.addButton(str(i), press, 0, i)
app.stopScrollPane()
```

For option 2, get rid of the list of `setButton()` calls, and replace them with a call to a new function: `updateButtons()`.

Then, in that function, have something like:

```
def updateButtons(btn=None):
    m = app.getScale("scroller") * 10
    for i in range(1, 13):
        app.setButton (str(i), str(m+i))
```

You'll also probably want to set the range on the scale: `app.setScaleRange("scroller", 0, 9)`

And, register the scale to call the `updateButtons()` function, instead of  `press`

You'll also need to do the equivalent maths for the button presses, as they return their ID, not their value.